# Sample custom shared_ptr - how do I pass constructor parameters - Do I use a variadic template here?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am trying to write a very simple shared pointer class just for practice and I was confused as to how I can pass parameters to a class that I want wrapped up in my shared pointer. I am not worried currently about the logic of the shared pointer class I made.I simply want to know how I can pass parameters to it.

This is the code

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int a,std::string str)
    {
    }
    int a;
};

template <typename t>
class shared
{
    public:
    shared() 
    {
        _mtype = new t();
        counter = counter +1;
    }

   ....
   ....
};

int main()
{
    shared<foo> f(12,"Hello"); //This will fail - How do I modify shared constructor to accept generic no and type of parameters so that it could initialize those types with the parameters
    f->a = 12;
    std::cout << f->a;
}
```

Currently foo has an `int` and a `string` as a constructor and its easy to hard code that into `shared` constrcutor and simply initialize `foo` with the constructor parameters of `shared`. I wanted to know how I can make my `shared` class a little more generic so I can use it with classes who constructor parameters are unknown.I am not super familiar with variadic templates but is that what I am suppose to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you need to declare and define a variadic template for constructor.

```
template <typename Args...>
shared(Args&&... args) 
{
    _mtype = new t(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    counter = counter +1;
}
```